# Use eval function with 'mean()' and 'median()'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate mean and median from of a dataframe so I put them in a list as follows:

```
comb_methods = ['median','mean']
```

I use a loop and use eval function to make the functions callable, and calculate the result and add it as a new column to the dataframe

```
for combin in comb_methods:
 combination = eval(combin)
 heartdata[combin] = heartdata.combination(axis=1)
```

I get the following error.

> name 'median' is not defined

I'm trying to understand why this is occurring for hours but I can't figure it out!

Comment: `eval` evaluates the input string as if it were code; just putting "median" somewhere is not a valid Python command

Comment: @ifly6 that's what I'm looking for! using mean or median as a callable, when I simply use `heartdata['mean'] = heartdata.mean(axis=1)` it works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `getattr` instead of `eval`:

```
for combin in comb_methods:
    heartdata[combin] = getattr(heartdata, combin)(axis=1)
```

`getattr` looks for the attribute of a given object with a name as a string. Writing

```
getattr(heartdata, 'median')
```

returns `heartdata.median` (a method which we then call with the `axis=1` argument).

`eval` on the other hand simply evaluates whatever string you pass onto it. So

```
eval('median')
```

is the same as simply typing `median` (without quotes) on a Python script. Python will believe that `median` is a variable, and will throw the error you see when it can't find said variable.

Comment: Although if you're going to modify columns in a loop, note that subsequent operations will use **all** columns for calculating the resulting statistic, **including the column(s) you added in the loop itself**. This will mess up your results, so I suggest you calculate the columns first, stored them in a structure (e.g. `dict`) and only add them to the dataframe afterwards.

Comment: My bad! I copied the first two code lines from @jfaccioni 's answer with geattr instead of getattr without verifying! Thank you everyone it's working

Comment: thank you @jfaccioni for this remark I really missed this important detail!!!